# Running nodejs command on gocd pipeline

Tags: node.js, shell, npm, go-cd

I created a new `gocd pipeline` and have three `shell script` files to run on different stages.

The problem is the go agent doesn't know `npm`.

`Note:` I have npm installed on the machine with go agent and I manually run the shell script from the pipeline.

Here is my shell script to install the packages.

```
#!/bin/sh
npm install
```

The error:

```
01:34:43.674 [go] Start to execute task: <exec command="./install.sh" />.
01:34:43.680 ./install.sh: line 3: npm: command not found
01:34:43.814 [go] Current job status: failed.
```

Answer (score 4):

**Problem**

Assuming you have npm/nodejs installed on the agent, the problem probably lies in the fact the user doesn't have its PATH environment variable configured to look into the folder npm was installed in.

**Solution**

1) You can specify the **whole path** (/usr/bin/npm) when creating a task.

2) You can edit the .bashrc/.bash_profile of the user running the gocd agent server. In which case you'll be able to call '/usr/bin/npm' without the path prepended.

#### Example Working Configuration

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Consider modification of the agent init script. Changing .bashrc/.bash_profile of the user running the gocd agent does not work because the go agent insulates itself from the calling environment. So on our systems we add these PATH items to the go agent startup scripts. (I use puppet to create agents. The default agent init scripts are not that good - you need to *own* them.)